# turn around sparse matrix

Tags: numpy, operators, scipy, sparse-matrix

I got some sparse matrix like this

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>from scipy.sparse import *
>>>A = csr_matrix((np.identity(3)))

>>>print A
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
```

For better understanding `A` is something like this:

```
>>>print A.todense()
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

And I would like to have an operator (let us call it `op1(n)` ) doing this:

```
>>>A.op1(1)
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

=> makes the last `n` columns the first `n` ones,
so

```
>>>A == A.op1(3)  
true
```

. Is there some build-in solution, (EDIT:) that returns a sparse matrix again?
The solution with `roll`:

```
X = np.roll(X.todense(),-tau, axis = 0)
print X.__class__
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scipy.sparse` doesn't have `roll`, but you can simulate it with `hstack`:

```
from scipy.sparse import *
A = eye(3, 3, format='csr')
hstack((A[:, 1:], A[:, :1]), format='csr')    # roll left
hstack((A[:, -1:], A[:, :-1]), format='csr')  # roll right
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = np.identity(3)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.roll(a, -1, axis=0)
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> a == np.roll(a, 3, axis=0)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: works perfectly! returns a ndarray and no matrix? is there a different one?